# Elisp Calling Go Code with Different Result

Tags: debugging, go, emacs

[This question is on the back of this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dominikh/go-mode.el/issues/200), when executing `godef-jump` on code on some named imports (but not all), it fails with the error that `godef: no declaration found for <the gx.thing we're godef-jump'ing>`.

Basically I'm a bit stuck with where to go next in my debugging. I've changed the code in `go-mode.el` to use the `-debug` flag with `godef`, and the outputs are different, from CLI is successful like this:

```
$ godef -f main.go gx.GetPackageRoot
/home/tomato/ipfs/src/github.com/whyrusleeping/gx/gxutil/pm.go:50:6
```

Whereas in Emacs it fails with the `godef: no declaration found for <the gx.thing we're godef-jump'ing>` error.

With the debug flag enabled, CLI:

```
$ godef -debug -t -f /home/tomato/ipfs/src/github.com/whyrusleeping/gx/main.go -o 565
2017/06/20 13:29:14 exprType tuple:false pkg: *ast.SelectorExpr gx.GetPackageRoot [
2017/06/20 13:29:14 exprType tuple:false pkg: *ast.Ident gx [
2017/06/20 13:29:14 exprType tuple:false pkg: *ast.ImportSpec gx "github.com/whyrusleeping/gx/gxutil" [
2017/06/20 13:29:14 ] -> 0x0, Type{package "" *ast.ImportSpec gx "github.com/whyrusleeping/gx/gxutil"}
2017/06/20 13:29:14 ] -> 0xc420276140, Type{package "" *ast.ImportSpec gx "github.com/whyrusleeping/gx/gxutil"}
2017/06/20 13:29:14 member Type{package "" *ast.ImportSpec gx "github.com/whyrusleeping/gx/gxutil"} 'GetPackageRoot' {
2017/06/20 13:29:14 } -> &{func GetPackageRoot 0xc4203ac3f0 <nil> <nil>}
2017/06/20 13:29:14 exprType tuple:false pkg: *ast.Ident GetPackageRoot [
2017/06/20 13:29:14 exprType tuple:false pkg: *ast.FuncType func() (string, error) [
2017/06/20 13:29:14 ] -> 0x0, Type{type "" *ast.FuncType func() (string, error)}
2017/06/20 13:29:14 ] -> 0xc420138140, Type{func "" *ast.FuncType func() (string, error)}
2017/06/20 13:29:14 ] -> 0xc420138140, Type{func "github.com/whyrusleeping/gx/gxutil" *ast.FuncType func() (string, error)}
/home/tomato/ipfs/src/github.com/whyrusleeping/gx/gxutil/pm.go:50:6
GetPackageRoot func() (string, error)
```

Emacs:

```
2017/06/20 13:31:18 exprType tuple:false pkg: *ast.SelectorExpr gx.GetPackageRoot [
2017/06/20 13:31:18 exprType tuple:false pkg: *ast.Ident gx [
2017/06/20 13:31:18 exprType tuple:false pkg: *ast.ImportSpec gx "github.com/whyrusleeping/gx/gxutil" [
2017/06/20 13:31:18 ] -> 0x0, Type{package "" *ast.ImportSpec gx "github.com/whyrusleeping/gx/gxutil"}
2017/06/20 13:31:18 ] -> 0xc4201fde50, Type{package "" *ast.ImportSpec gx "github.com/whyrusleeping/gx/gxutil"}
2017/06/20 13:31:18 member Type{package "" *ast.ImportSpec gx "github.com/whyrusleeping/gx/gxutil"} 'GetPackageRoot' {
2017/06/20 13:31:18 } -> <nil>
2017/06/20 13:31:18 ] -> 0x0, Type{bad "" <nil> }
godef: no declaration found for gx.GetPackageRoot
```

I've used `strace` to confirm that the expected binary is being called with the expected flags.

I guess the next thing I should do is find out where/how this `2017/06/20 13:29:14 member Type{package "" *ast.ImportSpec gx "github.com/whyrusleeping/gx/gxutil"} 'GetPackageRoot' {` line of output from the debugs is, since it is the next line of debug that differs, but maybe somebody has some better ideas or can already see what's going on here.

Comment: Please complete this question so that it is pretty much standalone. Summarize the other question or whatever, to make this question intelligible on its own. As it stands now the question is itself unclear.

Comment: @Drew fixed the question and figured out the answer and posted it, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Thanks....................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that Emacs was not aware of my `GOPATH` environment variable, this was resolved by adding this to `exec-path-from-shell-copy-envs` in my initialization files, like so:

```
(exec-path-from-shell-copy-envs '("PATH" "GOPATH"))
```

Comment: Indeed, any issue along the lines of "the results of running a command from Emacs are different to running the same command outside Emacs" is very likely to be related to environment variables.